# Bugs showing up as Unparented

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-workitem

Recently, the bugs or defects are showing up as Unparented in VSTS. They have been tagged to the correct parent but still the issue is there. Please let know on how this issue can be resolved.

Comment: What do you mean by "tagged" to the correct parent? Can you provide some screenshots showing the unparented bugs and the link section for one of the bugs?

Comment: To cite an example for tagging, there is this Defect X. Have created a task Y under this defect item. For the task, I link it to the parent X under the Links section. This linking is correct but in the sprint backlog screen, it shows as Unparented

Comment: Are the tasks showing up as unparented, or are the bugs? Do you have bugs configured to be treated as requirements, or as tasks? If you had bugs configured to be treated as requirements and changed them to be treated as tasks, then the bugs would start showing up as unparented because they do not have a parent PBI/User story.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the defect WIT is a customized WIT, so you need to **add the defect WIT under Requirement backlog** (same level as PBI/user story). Then the defect WIT will be shown in sprint backlog.

Detail steps as below:

In process page (https://account.visualstudio.com/_settings/process) -> select the process template you are using -> Backlog levels Tab -> Edit/Rename Backlogs -> select defect WIT -> Save.

[image]

[image]

Now, you will see the defect WIT and the children tasks are show in sprint backlog.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is not ok with the question I think.
I see Bug unparented whatever is its parent link.

I got "Bug" in "Other work item types"
I got "Technical Story" & "User story" in Requirement Backlog
"Bug" is not shown here.

I can't add Bug in Requirement Backlog  because already existing in "Other work item". Even if I Disable the work item type Bug, I can't create it again.

[Config process scrum / backlog levels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQM8N.png)